# MySQL: remove rows from table if exist in other table with condition

Tags: mysql

I need to remove rows from "t2", if "t2.t1_id" exists in "t1" and "t1.status = E"

tables structure,

t1 (structure)

```
id      status
1         E
2         A
3         A
4         E
5         C
```

t2 (structure)

```
id     t1_id
1           1
2           2
3           3
4           4
5           5
```

note: t1_id forign key refer to table_1.id

thanks,

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
DELETE FROM t2 WHERE t1_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE status='E'
)
```

The expected result after the query would be:

```
id     t1_id
2           2
3           3
5           5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
DELETE t2,t1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t1.status = 'E';
```